# What are the caveats of having a global event bus?

Tags: java, events

Is it a bad design to have a global event bus in your application?
How to make sure you don't end up with a tightly coupled set of components talking to each other all over the application?
Can you think of a mechanism/tools/library in Java world to enforce some discipline on it?

Comment: A GWT web application, but that isn't very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with a global event bus i.e. an event bus which is accessible to every component (class or object) in your application, is that you have no control who will use the event bus.

If you are the sole developer or are working with a close knit team, it is possible to agree on the conditions when a component can use the event bus. Otherwise all bars are off.

Having said that, there should be a possibility to communicate with the event bus otherwise having it is pointless. By introducing an proxy for the eventbus who is responsible for the actual firing of the event, you can control who depends on the proxy.

By using dependency injection (via a framework like [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or hand-rolled) you can automatically provide the proxy state making the dependency on the eventbus explicit.

Comment: This approach seems reasonable. You can hard-code/configure who can talk using this event bus. To enforce isolated communication among related components you might need local event buses. This is a bit hard to configure with Guice I think (wiring a different instance of the same thing in a different context), or I might be missing something.